# Chrome browser reports obsolete cipher (AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1)

Tags: tls, chrome, ciphers

Jboss 6 server is configured to support these ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

But the Chrome browser reports:

> The connection to this site uses a strong protocol (TLS 1.2), a strong
>   key exchange (ECDHE_RSA), and an obsolete cipher (AES_256_CBC with
>   HMAC-SHA1)

Should we remove all _SHA ones from the server configuration?

However, the nmap ssl scan shows, they are all A grade ciphers:

```
$ nmap -p 443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers.nse host-name

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp160k1) - A
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp160k1) - A
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp160k1) - A
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp160k1) - A
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not the SHA1 but the CBC. You need to offer an [AEAD cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) like the GCM ciphers or   CHACHA20-POLY1305. From the Chromium (base for Chrome) projects [documentation about cipher suites](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls#TOC-Cipher-Suites):

> To avoid this message, use TLS 1.2 and prioritize an ECDHE cipher suite with AES_128_GCM or CHACHA20_POLY1305. Most servers will wish to negotiate TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.

You don't offer any of these ciphers so you get this warning. See also [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/google-chrome-your-connection-to-website-is-encrypted-with-obsolete-cryptograph/83891#83891) for more details. See also the source code of Chromium, notable the function `ObsoleteSSLStatusForCipherSuite` in [net/ssl/ssl_cipher_suite_names.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/ssl/ssl_cipher_suite_names.cc) where this check is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I think your problem is in the certificate you are using. Your certificate must be done using a good cypher. That's the Chrome message you are seeing. You need to issue the certificate again using sha2 and a good cypher this time.</s>

I recommend to you to use the online tool [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to test your site. It will test your certificate, your configuration, etc. And it provide you a grade. A+ is the best. And also it recommends to you how to proceed to solve your problems. A very nice tool!

EDIT: maybe this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/google-chrome-your-connection-to-website-is-encrypted-with-obsolete-cryptograph/83891#83891) can help you

Comment: it does not look like , I did a sslscan using Kali Linux and here is info about certificate:   SSL Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
RSA Key Strength:    2048

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by re-configuring the Jboss ciphers without SHA ones. Now the Chrome does not shows any security warnings.

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```